# Convert Ubuntu to XUbuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu, linux

I am currently running Ubuntu 9.04 64 bit, with separate home directory.

What is the best way to convert Ubuntu to XUbuntu?

1. Reformat and install XUbuntu.
2. Install xubuntu-desktop using apt-get, and remove ubuntu-desktop.
3. Install xfce4 using apt-get only. Is xfce is the major different between Ubuntu and XUbuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 -> Is correct, and is the cleanest form
2 -> Is correct, but packages may be broken or something like that. After that, do `sudo apt-get autoremove` to clean unnecessary packages.
3 -> The same that 2.

My favourite is the option 1, but if you need do it fast or save configuration/data ... do 2 or 3.

Best regards!

Answer (score 6):

`apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` is the simplest approach, this will install the xfce desktop and all the software that usually comes with xubuntu.

You could also install the packages individually, but you'll end up installing most of the same stuff, with a lot more effort. I wouldn't even consider re-installing, there's no real benifit.

Answer (score 3):

Best tutorials for this on the web for every recent version of Ubuntu:

http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/xfce

http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexfce

Answer (score 1):

The above is correct. In addition, removing `ubuntu-desktop` will not remove what it pulled in; you may find `deborphan` useful to remove the remaining cruft.

Comment: Using aptitude to mark what's installed because you asked for it and what's installed because it's a dependency of another package can help get rid of stuff you don't need.